# Download all drug adverse events

Tags: openfda

I downloaded the adverse events quarterly data files from the FEARS website and I merged and cleaned them to use them in my next analytics pipeline. I was asked if I can download all the drug adverse events with demographic information (sex, age,..), drug name, indication for use, reactions, outcome, etc directly from the openFDA API. Is that possible?

Comment: this will download everything from faers -- https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/FDA%20Adverse%20Event%20Reporting%20System -- with detailed description -- http://www.asdfree.com/2014/07/analyze-fda-adverse-event-reporting.html

Answer (score 2):

There is limited demographic data in the adverse event records, but the ones that you asked for are on the patient record:

`patient: {
  "patientonsetage": "59",
  "patientonsetageunit": "801",
  "patientsex": "2",
  "patientweight": "78",
  "patientdeath": {
    "patientdeathdate": "20030401",
    "patientdeathdateformat": "102"
  },
  "drug": [...],
  "reaction": [...],
}`

Most of the reference information can be found [here](https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference/) (we are currently refactoring the website, so there will be a few  new references on some fields that were recently added).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Hans Nelsen. So, can I download all the drug adverse events data, with all columns, as zipped JSON data? I want to download everything available on the openFDA drug adverse events database. I want to use it for machine learning analytics and I want all variables and all observations.